# Get the page IDs of a Particular Menu item's submenu

Tags: sub-menu

I have been searching. And searching. I have found many, many ways to get the submenu, but they all seem to include the <li> and classes. I do not want that. I want to get an array page IDs of a particular menu's subnavigation pages.

wp_list_pages gets me close, but it seems to be grabbing those from the pages area in WP, not the navigation. I deleted "Concrete" from the nav because it was not in the correct order using wp_list_pages. But Concrete still showed.

And wp_list_pages generates an array of the complete code that can't seem to break apart to do what I want.

I just need the submenus page IDs in an array. It would be 9 IDs.

Below is the menu item "menu-item-127" that is my target. I want to get the page IDs of it's subnav. I do not want to get an array of the menu with the <li><a> etc.

```
<li id="menu-item-127" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-127"><a href="/services/">Services</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-511" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-511"><a href="/services/construction/">Construction</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-514" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-514"><a href="/services/environmental/">Environmental</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-517" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-517"><a href="/services/safety-management/">Safety Management</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-515" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-515"><a href="/services/mechanical/">Mechanical</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-510" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-510"><a href="/services/civil-construction/">Civil Construction</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-520" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-520"><a href="/services/concrete/">Concrete</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-516" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-516"><a href="/services/medical/">Medical</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-512" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-512"><a href="/services/consulting/">Consulting</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-513" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-513"><a href="/services/energy-fueling/">Energy/Fueling</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you looked into `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following function:

```
function wpse_290320_get_page_ids_from_menu( $menu_id, $submenu_id )
{
    $menus = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id );
    $pages = array();

    foreach( $menus as $menu )
    {
        if( $submenu_id == $menu->menu_item_parent && 'page' == $menu->object )
        {
            $pages[] = $menu->object_id;
        }
    }

    return $pages;
}

$menu_id = 26; 
$submenu_id = 3298;

$pages = wpse_290320_get_page_ids_from_menu( $menu_id, $submenu_id );
```

You can find the menu ID if you select a menu from Dashboard > Appearances > Menus, then in the URL. For example, if the URL is http://single.dev/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=26 then 26 is the menu ID.

And for submenu ID, according to the example, 127 is the submenu ID.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for and works perfectly!! Thank you so much, I truly appreciate it. I was pulling my hair out.

Comment: And if you want to get the IDs of ALL subnav items, pages AND posts, remove "&& 'page' == $menu->object" from the code leaving "if( $submenu_id == $menu->menu_item_parent)"

Comment: Yes, I made it more specific as you wanted the "page" so I wanted to make sure to get only page IDs :)